# Sum of vlookups for each value in a row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

There should be a way to do this, and yet I'm struggling...

***==The Data==***

**Sheet1**

```
        A           B
+---------------+-------+
| Fishy_Product | Price |
+---------------+-------+
| Cod           | $9.99 |
| Trout         | $8.99 |
| Haddock       | $6.99 |
| Kippers       | $3.99 |
+---------------+-------+
```

**Sheet2**

```
       A            B         C       D        E
+------------+-------------+-----+--------+---------+
|            | Total Spend | Cod | Trout  | Haddock |
+------------+-------------+-----+--------+---------+
| Customer 1 | ?           |   1 |        |       3 |
| Customer 2 | ?           |     |      2 |         |
| Customer 3 | ?           |   2 |      2 |       2 |
+------------+-------------+-----+--------+---------+
```

***==The Challenge==***

For each customer, I need to calculate *Total Spend* by multiplying 'purchases' in Sheet2 by the 'product/price' in Sheet1.  For example, I could calculate *Total Spend* for Customer 1 along the lines of:
`=(C2*vlookup(c1,'Sheet1!A:B,2,0))+(D2*vlookup(D1,'Sheet1!A:B,2,0))+(E2*vlookup(E1,'Sheet1!A:B,2,0))` etc.

**BUT** new products are added to Sheet1 all the time.

As soon as "kippers" gets added as Column F, I'd have to manually loop back and update all the formula. (Note, whenever a new product gets added to Sheet1, it automatically appears as a new column in Sheet2, due to the formula being used). Personal laziness aside, the concern is that I may not spot when updates are needed, and work from incorrect totals.

Is there any way to calculate *Total Spend* without having to manually update the formula each time a new item/column is added?

Many thanks in advance to anyone who could help me with this.

P.S. I should add that I'm working in Google Sheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `SUMPRODUCT()` to do your calculations:

[image]

Formula in `B8`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A$5=C$7:E$7)*(B$2:B$5*C8:E8))
```

Drag down, but note that it won't automatically update when products are added.

---

To clarify, order of products is irrelevant:

[image]

The same results.

Comment: @MátéJuhász. It will work regardless of order.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!

I had no idea SUMPRODUCT could behave in this way. I was able to take this solution and go a step further by changing the formula to operate on entire rows/columns like this:

`=SUMPRODUCT(('BYO Products Import'!B$2:B=$H$1:$1)*('BYO Products Import'!$E$2:E*$H13:13))`

...in my case the the numbers would automatically update when new columns were added. 

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

*With little modification in data orientation this issue can be solved:*

**:Caveat:**

*The shown method works with Google Sheet as well Excel.*

[image]

- Formula in cell sheet2 H19 & fill down:

  ```
   =IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!G13,$G$19:$K$22,{3,4,5},FALSE))*Sheet1!H13,"")
  ```

**N.B.**

*If the SUMPRODUCT has a single argument, it behaves much like the SUM. But when the SUMPRODUCT has multiple arguments, it returns the sum of the product of its arguments. Here is working with single argument.*

*{3,4,5} are column I, J & K in data range $G$19:$K$22, and are adjustable.*

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Answer (score 0):

You select a big area for VLookup Table so as to accomodate all items. say take 5000 Rows. Now every time when new items are added, you please again sort the two columns A and B on A, containing items. Moment you SORT it will behave correct,so no problem.

Thanks.